# Ajax not working properly when I tried to call it on same page again

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP page which has two sections (top and bottom). The top section has a table where I have options to Edit the data.

Once the Edit button is pressed, the content is loaded at the bottom of page and the user can change the data.

Here is part of my PHP page:

```
            <div id="product_entry_<?php echo $id?>" class="product_entry_<?php echo $id?>">
                <tr>
                    <td><font size=2px><?php echo $date?></font></td>
                    <td><font size=2px><?php echo $ProductName?></font></td>
                    <td><font size=2px><?php echo $Category.' / '.$SubCategory?></font></td>
                    <td><font size=2px><?php echo $MRP.' / '.$Price?></font></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="padding:2px 2px;font-size: 9px;line-height: 10px;" onClick="DirectPromoteSubmit(<?php echo $id?>)">Promote</button></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="padding:2px 2px;font-size: 9px;line-height: 10px;" onClick="RePromoteSubmit(<?php echo $id?>)">Edit</button></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="padding:2px 2px;font-size: 9px;line-height: 10px;" onClick="DelPromoteSubmit(<?php echo $id?>)">X</button></td>
                </tr>
            </div>

            <!-- page where data is loaded -->
            <div class="box box-warning" id="RePromoteReplace">
             ....some html content here...
            </div>
```

Here is my Javascript:

```
            function RePromoteSubmit(id){
                //alert('got into Edit Promotions');
                var dataString = "id="+ id;
                alert(dataString);
                if(dataString=='')
                {
                    alert('Some Problem Occurred, Please try Again');
                }
                else
                {
                //alert('into post');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "SellerPanel/post_repromote.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        //$("#tweet").val('');
                        //$("#preview").hide();
                        $("#RePromoteReplace").replaceWith(html);
                        alert('Product Successfully Loaded!!! Edit(Optional) & Click Promote Button in bottom section')
                    }
                    });
                }return false;
                }
```

Here is my PHP page which loads the bottom section - post_repromote.php:

```
            <?php
            include("../dbconnection.php");
            include("session.php");
            if(!isset($_SESSION))
            {
                session_start();
            }

            $id=$_POST['id'];

            $query1=mysqli_query($con,"select promotiondata from sellerpromotions where id=$id");
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query1))
                {
                .....some code here.....
                }
            ?>
                        <div class="box box-warning">
                            <div class="box-header">
                            <h3 class="box-title">Fill Product Details</h3>
                            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body">

                        <!-- <form role="form " name="PromoteForm"> -->
                        <div>
                                <!-- text input -->
                            <table class="table">
                                ....some data here from query..
                            </table>        

                            <div class="box-header with-border">
                                        <h3 class="box-title">Upload your Product Image</h3>
                            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
                            <div class="box-body no-padding">
                                <div id='preview'>
                                    <?php if ($uploadid){ ?>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src=<?php echo "SellerPanel/uploads/".$imagename?> id="<?php echo $uploadid?>" alt="User Image" class='preview' style='width:340px;height:200px;border-color:black'/>
                                    <?php } 
                                    ?>
                                </div>    
                                <?php 

                                    include ("index_photo.php");

                                ?>

                                <!-- <span class="users-list-date">Yesterday</span> -->

                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                            <div class="box-footer">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="PromoteSubmit()">Promote</button>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                        </div><!-- /.box -->
            <?php }
            ?>
```

The problem I'am facing:

- I'am able to load the data when I press the Edit button first.
- When I press it again, I'm not able to load the new data unless I refresh the page and click the Edit button again.

I tried to read the id in JS and printed it, I found that id is being passed correctly.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

JS after using solution:

```
            function RePromoteSubmit(id){
            //alert('got into Edit Promotions');
            var dataString = "id="+ id;
            alert(dataString);
            function getRandomInt() {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10,6));
            }
            //var url = "SellerPanel/post_repromote.php?"+getRandomInt();
            //alert ("url is: "+ url);
            if(dataString=='')
            {
                alert('Some Problem Occurred, Please try Again');
            }
            else
            {
            //alert('into post');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SellerPanel/post_repromote.php?rnd="+getRandomInt();
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    //$("#tweet").val('');
                    //$("#preview").hide();
                    $("#RePromoteReplace").replaceWith(html);
                    alert('Product Successfully Loaded!!! Edit(Optional) & Click Promote Button in bottom section')
                }
                });
            }return false;
            }
```

Comment: Don't use font tags.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your callback to use `.html()` instead of `replaceWith()`: (in your original code)

```
 success: function(html){
       //$("#tweet").val('');
       //$("#preview").hide();
         $("#RePromoteReplace").html(html);
         alert('Product Successfully Loaded!!! Edit(Optional) & Click Promote Button in bottom section')
  }
```

I also recommend changing your selector to a `class` instead of an `ID`, you can do this by just adding an extra class in your HTML:

```
<div class="box box-warning promoReplace" id="RePromoteReplace">
```

and then updating the selector in your `success` callback:

```
$(".promoReplace").html(html);
```

---

Sidenote: For debugging, its usually easier to use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` (when using ajax, you usually would have the console open anyway)

Comment: wow, this solved the problem. But why replacewith and id attributes were failing it earlier?

Comment: using a class means that you can use it multiple times, an id will only work once.   And `replaceWith' was probably having an issue because of the same reason. Dont forget to mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your AJAX response is getting cached by the browser due to some server setting or page header. Easiest way to disable this is to append some randomly generated parameter to your url every time you send a request.

The function `getRandomInt` will generate a 6 digit random number. If you want to have more/less digits, change the second argument passed to `Math.pow`.

```
function getRandomInt() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.pow(10,6));
}
//then, inside your ajax function, use:
    url: "SellerPanel/post_repromote.php?rnd="+getRandomInt(),
```

Comment: Hi, can you please help me on how i can achieve this. I am sorry since I am a novice in ajax. Thanks.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that <code>url</code> should be generated again every time you make a request, so it's best to use the last line of my code sample _inside_ the ajax function.

Comment: I tried to use your code, but now i am not able to load any data. Am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Hi, i tried with updated changes, but still no luck. i have edited my question and added the new JS at the bottom. Can you please check.

Comment: You used ´url: "SellerPanel/post_repromote.php?"+getRandomInt();´ replace ; with ,

Comment: My bad, have updated my answer. Change the semi-colon to a comma, @Amandeep, since it's an object property.

Comment: replaced ; with , JS is being called now but the problem still persist and new data doesn't load.

Comment: I think in that case your problem might be elsewhere, did you try M.Doye's solution?